# mysql problem when doing 2 counts in the same query

Tags: mysql

First of all, apologies if this seems like a very dumb question, I have just started working with mySQL.

I have 2 tables:

1- [Customer_courier_chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep33L.png)

2- [Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5mNF.png)

Basically I want to do a query to count the amount of messages from a customer and the amount of messages from a courier. When I do an individual query to look for it, it works well but when I do both in the same query it returns different values.

The following query provides good results:

```sql
SELECT o.*, count(j.from_id) AS messages_courier
FROM test.orders o
INNER JOIN test.customer_courier_chat_messages j ON j.from_id = j.courier_id and o.order_id = j.order_id
Group BY o.order_id;
```

**Results of the previous query** [messgaes from courier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9heUS.png)

The following one also provides good results:

```sql
SELECT o.*, count(k.from_id) AS messages_customer
FROM test.orders o
INNER JOIN test.customer_courier_chat_messages k ON k.from_id = k.customer_id and o.order_id = k.order_id
Group BY o.order_id;
```

**Results of the previous query** [messages from customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35SO4.png)

The main problem comes when I try to do both in the same query as the output is not correct.

```sql
SELECT o.*, count(j.courier_id) messages_courier, count(k.from_id) AS messages_customer
FROM test.orders o
INNER JOIN test.customer_courier_chat_messages j ON j.from_id = j.courier_id and o.order_id = j.order_id
INNER JOIN test.customer_courier_chat_messages k ON k.from_id = k.courier_id and o.order_id = k.order_id
Group BY o.order_id;
```

**Results of previous query** [not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmCEs.png)

Based on the results of the 2 invidiual queries, the previous one should provide:

```
order_id    |city_code    |messages_courier    |messages_customer|
59528555    | ES          | 2                  | 5               |
11223344    | FR          | 3                  | 4               |
```

But, it actually provides:

```
order_id    |city_code    |messages_courier    |messages_customer|
59528555    | ES          | 4                  | 4               |
11223344    | FR          | 9                  | 9               |
```

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advanced.

Kindly regards,
J

Comment: Placing images of code into your question is not helpful.  Pasting textual code into your question is helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you include SQL as text? Trying to click between image links make it hard to answer. With "not working as expect", what did you expect? Look at [group by handing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and consider enabling 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'.

Comment: 'correct messgaes' indeed. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.city_code,
       SUM(m.from_id = m.courier_id) AS messages_courier,
       SUM(m.from_id = m.customer_id) AS messages_customer
FROM test.orders o INNER JOIN test.customer_courier_chat_messages m 
ON o.order_id = m.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id, o.city_code;
```

Comment: Better solution than mine I must say.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer forpas. It is solving my question !!!

Comment: @Julius fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You are first joining the table then using the count. You have to first pick get the count then use the join -

```
SELECT o.*, j.cnt messages_courier, k.cnt AS messages_customer
FROM test.orders o
INNER JOIN (SELECT order_id, COUNT(*) CNT
              FROM test.customer_courier_chat_messages
             WHERE from_id = courier_id
             GROUP BY order_id) j ON o.order_id = j.order_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT order_id, COUNT(*) CNT
              FROM test.customer_courier_chat_messages
             WHERE from_id = customer_id
             GROUP BY order_id) k ON o.order_id = k.order_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Ankit! This one also works :)